# org.apache.commons doesn't exist when using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jdbc

I am trying to include `DbUtils` in my Java project.

I have included this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And then in my java file:

```
package mypackage;
import org.apache.commons.DbUtils;
```

When I run `mvn package` I got:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
[ERROR] [4,26] package org.apache.commons does not exist
```

Which other dependency should I include?

Comment: did you try the name you included? ie package commons-dbutils.*

Comment: commons-dbutils cannot be imported

Comment: @giò have you included this jar, or has it been downloaded and added to classpath. try generating classpath once.

Comment: I am using Maven, I don't need to include the jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;
```

should fix it

Comment: Thanks that worked! I even tried import org.apache.commons.dbutils  but it was not working, dunno why

Comment: Because you need to import the class `DbUtils` located in the package `org.apache.commons.dbutils`. Alternatively you could import all classes in this package with `import org.apache.commons.dbutils.*;`.